# Add Wordpress menu css classes to <span class="">

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Want to add the CSS class added to the Wordpress menu as shown below
[image: CSS Meny]

to my menu

```
      wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'theme_location'    => 'header', 
        'container'         => false, 
        'items_wrap'        => '%3$s', 
        'after'             => '<span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa "></i></span>'
      ));
```

To create

```
<li>
  <a href="/">Dashboard</a> 
  <span class="icon-thumbnail">
  <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
  </span>
</li>
```

So, add the CSS class that was added to the `menu_item` within the Wordpress Admin to the `<i class="fa "></i>` in my menu. Therefore, looking like `<i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>`

Comment: Explain more what is not happening? What exactly you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
     'theme_location'    => 'header', 
     'container'         => false,
     'items_wrap'        => '%3$s',
));
```

In wp admin in css input box put this class

```
fa fa-reorder
```

This should fix the issue you need to add append fa class to add fontawesone icons.

EDIT:
This is the walker for bootstrap.

> https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Edit the code as per your need

This part in the walker is to be edited for fixing your issue.

```
if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ) {
  $pos = strpos( esc_attr( $item->attr_title ), 'glyphicon' );

  if ( false !== $pos ) {
      $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;';
  } else {
      $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><i class="fa ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;';
  }
} else {
    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
}
```

This should fix the issue

Comment: Thank you. However, I need the class to be added to the '<i class="fa ">', so it outputs as '<i class="fa fa-reorder">' within the '<span class="icon-thumbnail">'. Therefore, whether it is with css input 'fa fa-reorder' or 'fa-reorder' I m still not achieving the outcome I need.

Comment: You need to create a walker for that. Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @Darren Mathers did that work? If yes mark this as solved.